# Display Top Three Items in a List by Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a list that is sorted by JS using data attributes. The list appears like this:

```
<li data-sortm="4">Migraines</li>
<li data-sortm="2">Stress</li>
<li data-sortm="2">Depression</li>
<li data-sortm="1">Anxiety</li>
<li data-sortm="1">Lack of Appetite</li>
<li data-sortm="1">Muscle Spasms</li>
<li data-sortm="0">Nausea</li>
<li data-sortm="0">Insomnia</li>
<li data-sortm="0">Pain</li>
<li data-sortm="0">PMS</li>
<li data-sortm="0">Seizures</li>
<li data-sortm="0">Fatigue</li>
```

What I would like to do is display the top three items and hide or remove the rest of the list. For example in the list above the top three would look like this:

```
<li data-sortm="4">Migraines</li>
<li data-sortm="2">Stress</li>
<li data-sortm="2">Depression</li>
```

There is one catch, while I would like the top three displayed if we have a setup like this:

```
<li data-sortm="4">Migraines</li>
<li data-sortm="3">Pain</li>
<li data-sortm="2">Stress</li>
<li data-sortm="2">Depression</li>
```

I would want to show all four since the last two are the same number.

How do I do this using jQuery?

I have considered using RegEx as I think that may be a way but RegEx is not an area I find easy to use.

Here is the code I am using to sort the list:

```
$(".medical-list li").sort(sort_li_medical).appendTo('.medical-list');
  function sort_li_medical(a, b){
    return ($(a).data('sortm')) < ($(b).data('sortm')) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

Note: I am using v2.1 of jQuery.

Comment: Can you provide your sorting code, so we can assist in modifying it?

Comment: @LaughDonor - Sure. I edited question to show this code.

Comment: Why the down vote? I am asking how to do something and attempting to learn how. The search I did didn't provide any clear answers or where I should be looking. Any guidance is welcome.

Comment: Why the down votes: Stack Overflow is usually a place you come when you have tried writing the come yourself. You just provided the task not any try. Whan that is said look at 1. `jQuery.fn.filter`. 2. `itCounter++` will add 1 to `itCounter` if its a number. 3. look at  `jQuery.fn.remove`

Comment: @NULL - I realize this. My problem is I haven't found a good place to start writing code. It is kind of hard to write code when I am unsure exactly where I should start. As stated above guidance is welcome. If someone was to say "Try reading about [name] jQuery method..." I would happily look over it and try to code it then edit my question if it didn't work. At this moment I am unsure where to start and I think RegEx may be possible but I am not familiar enough with RegEx to start coding.Edit: I just saw that you edited your question saying look at those jQuery functions. I will do that. TY

Comment: You want to show all items which have top 3 values?, e.g. for values 4,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0 then all are filtered away except those with values 4, 3 and 2

Comment: @Kunukn - Yes the top three values. In Your example of numbers I would want to show `4,3,3`

Comment: @Lynda bad example by me, what I meant was for values 5,5,3,3,3,3,2 do you want 5,5,3,3 or 5,5,3,3,3,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go, I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghm6R/) with what you're looking for.

Made use of the `.filter()` function and applied a `.hide()` to all that don't match the top tier.

```
var min = 0;
$(".medical-list li").filter( function(k, v) {
    if( k < 3 ) { //Top 3 will be shown
        min = parseInt($(v).data('sortm'));
        return false;
    } else //Anything else must equal to third one, or it's filtered
        return min > parseInt($(v).data('sortm'));
}).hide(); //Hide all that are not in the top 3
```

Of course, you would place this *after* your `li`'s are sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
var prevVal = -1;

var $collection = $('li[data-sortm]');
var $collectionToRemove = $collection.filter(function(index) {
  var thisVal = $(this).data('sortm');

  // if this is the 4 item or more and prev value != thisValue
  if ( index > 3 && prevVal != thisVal ) {
    prevVal = thisVal;
    return true;
  }
  prevVal = thisVal;
  return false;
});

$collectionToRemove.remove();
```

Not the fastest and not the prettiest code but i hope it explains the process

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wj6gP/

Pretty straightforward - count the # of times each number is used, mark the top 3+ with a class and then hide anything without it.

```
var unique_keys = {};
$.map($('li'), function(a) {    
    unique_keys[$(a).data('sortm')] = unique_keys[$(a).data('sortm')] + 1 || 1; 
});

var sorted = Object.keys(unique_keys).sort().reverse();

var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) { 
    $('li[data-sortm=' + sorted[i] + ']').addClass('show');
    total += unique_keys[sorted[i]];
    if(total >= 3) {
         break;   
    }
}

$('li:not(.show)').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var count = 0;
var currentTop = -1;
$('li[data-sortm]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var sortm = $this.data('sortm');
    if (count >= 3) {
        if (count == 3 && currentTop == sortm) {
            currentTop = sortm;
            return;
        }
        $this.remove();
        return;
    }
    count++;
    currentTop = sortm;
});
```

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/Ty7R7/1/)